# Horizontal EditText scroll one character at a time

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-edittext

I'm using the following XML attributes for my `EditText`:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"
android:lines="1"
android:maxLines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:typeface="serif"
```

<strike>Currently, when the text of my `EditText` becomes longer than it's size, the cursor moves to the beginning, and all of the previous text is backed up out of sight.</strike>

When the text of my `EditText` becomes longer than it's size, a new line begins, and the height of the `EditText` stays the same.

I want my `EditText` to scroll similar to the Google search bar; once the text becomes too long, the cursor should remain at the end, and as further characters are typed, the previous text should move backwards only one character at a time.

Here's a [video](http://tinypic.com/r/2072cck/5) displaying my problem.

Comment: I tried it and it works correctly for me. What is exacly your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Ellipsize attribute, this solved a similar issue for us. TextViews also have the attribute `android:singleLine="true"` which is most likely to be what you are missing

Comment: Thanks. singleLine cleared it up. I had been avoiding it because people were saying it was deprecated, but it no longer appears to be.

Comment: Google doesn't use deprecation properly as far as I'm concerned - deprecated items are never removed in any version (compatibility concerns), nor does the javadoc ever tell you what to use instead... in this case though it doesn't appear to be deprecated http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine but you should be fine in either case!

Comment: Thanks for the link, that clears up why people think its deprecated and I don't. I'm not sure about whether that concerns layouts which aren't using an @ reference for a value or just concerns the generated android.R file you could use when doing it through code. However even if it is deprecated it wont be removed and if you have inputType/maxLines as well then newer versions of the SDK will just use that instead so don't get hung up about using it